# Why np.concatenate raise an error on same dimension np.arrays

Tags: python, arrays, valueerror, dimensions

I have a class with a 2D np.array as an attribute.

In one of the methods of the class, I would like to add a new column.

But when I try to add another 2D np.array on the left side, it seems that the second dimension of this new np.array is not recognized.

Because of this problem, I printed the type, shape, and content of the two np.arrays before the np.concatenate () command to make sure both array sizes were compatible with concatenation. This is the information about arrays:

```
INPUT MATRIX
Type input matrix - <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Shape input matrix - (3710, 2)
input matrix -
[['' '']
 ['RL1' 'TQMELDAADYAACAQA']
 ['RL1' 'QHLYGQTQPQLHAYPNANPQESAHF']
 ...
 ['US33A' 'FIVYVVLFTVAVQ']
 ['US33A' 'DAHL']
 ['US33A' 'QSFP']]

 ---------------------------------------------------------------
 NEW COLUMN
 Type new column - <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
 Shape new column - (3710, 1)
 new column - 
 [[1.]
  [1.]
  [1.]
  ...
  [1.]
  [1.]
  [1.]]
```

The command I used for the concatenation is:

```
self.dummy_input_matrix=np.concatenate((self.dummy_input_matrix, PSMs_col),axis=1)
```

where:

```
self.dummy_input_matrix = INPUT MATRIX
PSMs_col                = NEW COLUMN
```

as reported in the previous output.
The PSMs_col is an np.ones() that I reshaped to allow compatibility with the input matrix.
Below is the ValueError raised:

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)
```

Just to understand why "the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)" (despite the fact its shape is reported as (3710, 1) that means 2 dimensions not 1), I tried to force a second dimension on the PSMs_col hoping that was recognised. I wrote the same command but passing [PSMs_col] to the np.concatenate command:

```
self.dummy_input_matrix=np.concatenate((self.dummy_input_matrix, [PSMs_col]),axis=1)
```

I knew that this command did not make any sense based on the PSMs_col shape printed before. However, I think that the ValueError raised makes even less sense:

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 3 dimension(s)
```

Now it is recognised the third dimension I added with the [ ].

Does anyone have any ideas why the second dimension is not recognised in the first np.concatenate() command?

Thanks

Comment: I have to agree with you, the error you're getting makes little sense. I just tried to reproduce it, and I cannot, unfortunately. Doing a similar concatenate on a (100,2) and a (100,1) array worked for me, even with one having strings and the other numbers, like yours. Can you reproduce the problem with smaller arrays? And can you provide code to create the two input arrays that we could cut and paste and run on our own machines?

Comment: @joanis the problem is that I create the self.dummy_input_matrix variable in a Class module. I am afraid that if I do not provide the entire module, some issues may not emerge. Indeed, I tried to concatenate a hardcoded matrix and a 2D np.one() array and it works perfectly (like you did with your (100,2) and a (100,1) array concatenation). However, this is the line of code for the creation of the variable self.dummy_input_matrix=np.vstack([self.dummy_input_matrix, current_prot_pep]). But I do not think it will be so informative. I do not know how to share a shorter version of the code. Github?

Comment: Well, that does make it more complicated, it's true. As a troubleshooting approach, regardless of whether you end up sharing code, you could take a copy of your code and strip it down as much as you can, keeping only what's needed to make the bug appear. That process will either yield something small enough to share, or, with some luck, it might reveal the actual source of the problem.

Comment: Ok I will try. But in this case, it will take some time before I code a module simplified version. In the meantime, I hope you do not forget this post. Thanks for now. I will be back asap.

Comment: I've just "Follow"ed it, so SO will notify me when you update it or comment on it. So no worries, take the time you need.